# Hiding characters in Python by dots

Tags: python, authentication

I'm doing a little user/password emulator with a super simple visual interface (using Tkinter) and I need to hide the characters when the user is typing his password.

I need to hide them by that kind of dots that all the systems use when you are going to login into somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TKinter's `Entry` widget has a `show` option. If you set this option to a single character (e.g. `*`), this character is displayed instead of the actual characters.

If you don't want the asterisk (`*`) character, you can try the the bullet (`•`, `"\u2022"` in Python).

Comment: Michel, one little question. How can I use the dot? the show='*' works perfect for the star, but show='\u2022' or show='"\u2022"' are not working. Thanks in advance.